# Preventing WAN access to a Database

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

How do I prevent WAN access to a particular database in SQLyog? I am able to grant full access to particular DB's, but not able to prevent them. I have a Web APP that runs on an internal server and accesses MySQL on the same server.  I have created a SQL user with my workstations IP, but I am receiving access denied from dbconnect when I run the APP from my workstation.

Thanks,

Tony Cripps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not allow connections from anything other than what you've specified. If you want to *disallow* access from a particular IP or network, then that mean that you've already gone and granted access to them.

1. Review the [`CREATE USER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/account-names.html) syntax, particularly the section on specifying hostnames.
2. Review the user accounts that you've already created:

   ```
   SELECT user, host, password FROM mysql.user;
   ```

   And then re-create them as necessary.

Other than than that, if you want to completely disallow WAN access then you should be looking at your firewall settings, not MySQL.

Comment: My firewall does not allow port 3306 access except if your on the whitelist.

Comment: @user3099756 well then, you need to look at your grants if you don't want certain users accessing certain databases.

Comment: Yes, totally correct. I was having a brain malfunction Friday.  What I need to really do is my internal only app to a separate Virtual Host that is not accessable from the WAN.Thanks..